# После сортировки массива PHP появляется последний элемент=1

Tags: php, массивы, сортировка

массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => CURRENT/ELLIOTT
)
```

после

```
$rs = array_unique($rs);
$rs[] = natcasesort($rs);
```

становится

```
[0] => CURRENT/ELLIOTT
[1] => 1
```

Откуда последнее значение?

Comment: откуда идея писать $rs[] = natcasesort($rs);

Answer (score 1):

Точно

```
natcasesort($rs);
```

Будет правильно